Locking Armature
How can I force that this bone always has 90° to the ground?


Assuming the ground is flat, oriented with a single world plane.
The simplest way, which is not mathematically perfect, is to make a bone way, way above the ground, and damped track that bone.

Shown at rest and pose.  "Bone" damped tracks "Bone.001".  Bone.001 has a world space limit location that drags it way out of the view frame in world Z.  (Doing this with a constraint makes editing more convenient than doing it with edit mode.)  When the armature is posed, at right, this keeps Bone pointed upward-- that is, perpendicular to the world Z plane.  Its rotation about the world Z axis remains free.
There are other ways to do this (parent to something with copied world rotation from something unparented; IK with rotation only, with a Y axis "pressure relief" child.)  Those other ways are mathematically perfect, but this way is simpler (and, good enough.)
Be careful of some potential techniques-- for example, trying to do this with a world or pose space limit rotation constraint would be unwise and lead to interpolation problems in some orientations.

thanks a lot - I'll give it a try
